# In the following sentence, would you need a comma before just in case and, if so, why?

Tags: commas, subordinate-clauses

> The man burned the article, just in case the man was dangerous.

OR

> The man burned the article just in case the man was dangerous.

Comment: It's difficult to say which is the more idiomatic when both examples sound unnatural (and one contains a typo). 'He locked the door, just in case the new neighbours were not to be trusted' is not wrong with the comma, but it would probably be dropped nowadays in the trend towards minimalist punctuation. I'd add it if I wanted a pause there. And that might well depend on the length of the clauses.

Comment: Given that the sentence reads as nonsense it's impossible to say whether a comma should be present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Typos aside, I believe you are talking about two different "man" personas in the same sentence.

Original: "The man burned the article, just in case the man was dangerous." OR "The maned burned the article just in case the man was dangerous."

My versions, for illustration:
"The spying man burned the article, just in case the approaching man was dangerous." OR 
"The spying man burned the article just in case the approaching man was dangerous."

I prefer a comma between the two parts, with my edited version.  Without a comma, it all becomes one big blob, coming a little too fast.  The momentary pause of the comma allows the scene of the spying man, burning an article (like a newspaper article?) to form clearly in the reader's mind before cutting to the scene of the approaching man, the uncertainty of who it might be, and the possibility of danger.